# Can I override the http status in a rest_framework permission class?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a custom permission class inheriting from `permissions.BasePermission`. I know you can override the `message` property for a custom message but can the http status also be overridden?  I'd like to return a 410 for an expired link.  Not sure if I am trying to create an unintended behavior.

Or maybe there's a better place for my logic?  Basically what I am trying to do is send a user an invitation link, they click the link and a request to get some model data is made.  If this model data was created more than 10 days ago, (it does have a `created_on` property) I want to return a 410.  I just haven't designed anything with this logic before and to me it smelled like a permission class but I could be wrong.

Comment: what about [custom exception handling](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)

Comment: I can create a custom exception as part of the solution but that doesn't really solve the design dilemma I am having.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

403 is something very meaningful than a ***Permission Denied*** error with status code 410.
Apart from that, You can't change the status code of the *Permission Denied* error in DRF (in a DRF way).

---

## Workaround to obtain the solution

Create a custom API exception class as:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException
from rest_framework import status


class GenericAPIException(APIException):
    """
    raises API exceptions with custom messages and custom status codes
    """
    status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    default_code = 'error'

    def __init__(self, detail, status_code=None):
        self.detail = detail
        if status_code is not None:
            self.status_code = status_code
```

and in your permission class,

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class FooPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if some_condition:
            raise GenericAPIException(detail="exception message", status_code=410)
        return True
```

Comment: So that feels like my solution might be flawed then.  My logic should probably live somewhere else.  I updated my question with what I am trying to achieve and I'd love your input.

Comment: I have seen your changes. What I suggest is, write your logic to display or return the response when a valid request comes and raise the exception , the GenericException if the link is expired.

Comment: And, I would do those logic in my views if I had choice

Answer (score 1):

If someone is wondering, you can also do this

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError


class FooPermission(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if some_condition:
            raise ValidationError(detail="Exception Message", code=410)
        return True
```

From DRF documentation: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#validationerror

Answer (score 1):

You can also

```
raise ValidationError({"details":"Authentication credentials were not provided"}, code=410)
```